# earliest + verb?

Tags: word-usage, idiomatic-language

> Examples of this theory can be **earliest** found in Alan's book.

The sentence is meant to say that the theory can for the first time be found in Alan's book. Is the use of "earliest" idiomatic?

Comment: I wouldn't. "Examples of this theory can be *found early* in Alan's book." would be better, meaning the theory was explained in the first chapters of the book. "earliest" should modify a noun.

Answer (score 3):

It makes sense, but let me say it this way: I had to read it a few times to understand what it says. It's generally **fairly awkward, stuffy, and formal** and I *wouldn't* describe it as idiomatic. Certainly it is **grammatically correct**, though. I would personally switch it and say:

> Examples of this theory can be found earliest in Alan's book.

or

> Examples of this theory appear first in Alan's book.

Comment: appear or appeared ?

Comment: appeared first, or first appeared?